# Is there a way to automatically add faces in proper places to this mesh?

Tags: faces

I have this mesh (.blend below):

[image: mesh]

I want to add faces so that the object is a solid, but with holes (marked with red O's):

[image: holes]

I know how to manually add faces by selecting vertices and hitting F. Is there a way to do this automatically, so I can tell Blender to turn this mesh into a solid object with holes in specific areas?

[image]

Comment: As far I understood the OP looking for a way to fill the space between the boundaries, like [this](http://imgur.com/6ouvu24) @MrZak.

Comment: @Carlo my bad, misunderstood the question. However I don't see any easy way to do that (if using mesh modeling) except for using Knife Project for cutting those borders automatically and then joining them. It will create horrible topology though.

Comment: You don't have to excuse @MrZak, I was not sure too. Knife Project can also be a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a mirror modifier, you will need edges exactly at the mirror boundary. If you have Clipping enabled on the modifier, you can quickly duplicate any edge or vertex and move it towards the boundary, each vertex will get stopped exactly there. Lock movement to an axis if needed. If you use extruding, later you will have to deselect edges before filling.

[image]

The part to be filled has to be closed. Close it by making more edges (F or Mesh > Edges > Make Edge/Face).

[image]

Looking at the side of the mesh in orthographic projection, border-select one column of vertices (B or Select > Border Select). This should be done in wireframe view, to select vertices behind faces. Then fill the area with triangles (Alt+F or Mesh > Faces > Fill).

[image]

If this filled more than needed, you will have to retry on a smaller region. Undo the fill and make some internal edges, then try again.

Comment: It looks promising, but I was not able to achieve such result for the figure in the provided blendfile. Were you?

Comment: @HalfKiloByte can you please edit your answer? without the info in your comment it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

**Use a boolean modifier**

[image]

- Add a Cube scaled to flat in the desired location without hole. You may not even need to be precise because your edges may be intended to be hidden in frame. Or use F as you mentioned above. Assume name window01.
- Create a sphere named  Sphere01.  Sphere01 will be the hole cutter.
- Add a boolean modifier [difference]  to window01.  Sphere01 is target of modifier .
- Position Sphere01 where the desired hole should be.  You may hide the sphere to view easily ,  or view in wireframe mode.  You can use multiple spheres or other deformations of the sphere.  You determine placement.
- Press apply button for the boolean modifier.
- Reshape hole produced by the boolean modifier on window01. You might enjoy proportional editing in edit mode for this.
- Duplicate window01 to new locations or repeat process for each new window.

Answer (score 3):

### Use Curves

Mesh tools are not quite good at performing this task compared to curve counterparts: they are not capable of recoginzing the "holes". Starting from a planar profile placed on the XY plane, **convert the Mesh to a Curve** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

[image]

Switch to **2D** and then **enable Cyclyc U** for all the several curves composing the figure.

[image]

From here you can extrude, or re-convert the curve to mesh with the same command seen before.

*Note: you'll always get a worse topology than the one achievable by hand modeling*